# Вертикальная карусель элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, javascript (можно jQuery) плагин карусели с адекватной поддержкой вертикальной ориентации.

Под адекватной поддержкой я понимаю нормальную анимацию переходов с сохранением шага карусели в 1 блок. Ниже на картинке пример использования карусели Slick. В этом плагине шаг анимации отличается от высоты текущего верхнего div и возникает ситуация, когда часть div скрылась, а другая часть еще видна.

[image: Вертикальная карусель]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swiper? http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/03-vertical.html Вместо "пагинатора" может быть и "скроллбар", а также есть возможность отображать N слайдов одновременно.